# How do I combine PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown with Command?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command

In sample project I have a button binded to a Command. It works as button-click event.
However, I would like to use PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown/Up event in in conjunction with Command.
For example LeftButtonDown - filling with green, LeftButtonUp -default filling.
Is there a neat way to do that?

```
        <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Command="{Binding ColourChange_command, Mode=OneWay}" Content="Fill with green" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Ellipse Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Black">
            <Ellipse.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColourChange}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LimeGreen" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Ellipse.Style>
        </Ellipse>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What's stopping you from handling the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event before the command is executed?

Comment: I want to get rid of any events in Code behind. So I'm looking for solution that allows to use Command in ViewModel.

Comment: Then you should read [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/). Use an interaction trigger.